# How can I remove heating blower fan from the blower motor - Mercedes-Benz 308D van?

Tags: vw, mercedes-benz, peugeot, fan

How I can remove the plastic fan from the axle of the heating blower motor?

The vehicle is a Mercedes-Benz 308D van from 1992. The blower motor is a [Bosch part number 0 130 007 027](http://www.boschmotorsandcontrols.co.uk/elektromotoren/produkt/0130007027/index.htm). I know that also all Mercedes 207D, 208D ,209D, 210D, 307D, 308D, 309D, 310D, 407D, 409D, 410D vans, Volkswagen LT 28, LT 55 vans and Peugeot 305 from years 1983-1984 use the same motor, so people having experience with these vehicles can also help me.

The motor is broken, and I got a new one, but now I need to take the plastic fan off the old one to use on the new motor. The plastic fan attached to the motor looks like this:

[image: bosch-013000702-blower-motor-with-fan-front]

and a photo from the other side:

[image: other side]

I tried holding the plastic fan with one hand pulling the motor as hard as I can without feeling that the plastic might brake and also tried hitting the axle of the motor from the other side with a hammer, but neither method made it move even a bit.

Trying to rotate the plastic fan in relation to the motor axle doesn't work because I can't get hold of the axle with any tool hard enough not to have it rotate when I rotate the plastic fan.

Comment: Can you add a picture of the new motor, particularly the shaft?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried some kind of penetrating oil? And possibly asking the parts store if there is a puller tool?